# Exporting reducer from a file called duck as store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Given that in a file called goose.js I have exported a reducer as such:

```
//reducer
const reducer = handleActions(
  {
    [setExchangeRate]: (state, { exchangeRate }) => ({
      ...state,
      exchangeRate
    }),
    [setExchangeCurrency]: (state, { exchangeCurrency }) => ({
      ...state,
      exchangeCurrency
    }),
    [setBaseCurrency]: (state, { baseCurrency }) => ({
      ...state,
      baseCurrency
    })
  },
  initialState
);
export default reducer;

const selectCurrencyExchange = state => state[MODULE_NAME];
```

and in another file called index.jas, I try to import the reducer and assigned it to a provider:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducer from "./redux/goose";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={reducer}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

is there a reason why I am getting 
*TypeError store.getState is not a function* error? Is it illegal to do this?

The dependencies I am using is react 16.8.2, react-redux 5.07, redux, redux actions, redux-define.

I welcome an example that allows me to use the reducer structure in goose.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-redux `Provider` is taking a store not a reducer.
You need to create the store with use of `createStore` function from redux library and pass to it your reducer. And after that you can pass the created store to the `Provider`.

Have a look at the basic example in [redux documentation](https://redux-docs.netlify.com/recipes/configuring-your-store#creating-the-store).